# Getting SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement error on JavaScript lint (using jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jslint

Why im getting "SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement" in the last line of this code:

```
var currentMonth = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#left").click(function(){
        $("#calendar").animate({opacity: "0"},"slow",function(){
            if (currentMonth === 1) {
                currentMonth = 12;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

in jslint to check my code.
Can you please tell me what part am I wrong, I'm still newbie in jQuery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not on the last line of code. It might be somewhere else in the code. One curly braces here and there changes the complete block of a code. So, try to find the extra/missing curly brace in the code by using online formatter tools

Comment: I agree, this piece of code looks correct.

Comment: Once you add directives, this lints in both the [new](http://jslint.com) and [old](http://old.jslint.com) JSLint. No problems. Is there code before or after what you included here? How are you running JSLint (from command line with node, from an IDE or text editor, etc)?

Comment: I use online http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php lint

Comment: It seems happy there too. I don't see any errors when submitting your code, above, on that page. Is there more code than what's in the snippet you posted? (Worth pointing out the OP is apparently using [javascript lint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javascriptlint/) at that link, above, which is a Python-based linter, [updated as recently as last October](http://sourceforge.net/p/javascriptlint/code/354/), not JSLint.)

Comment: I always see this happen in the Firefox Dev Tools Console only ,, it intermittently appears even when code is correct and braces are balanced.